# How to specify URL queryparameters deeplink manifest

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink, android-deep-link

The problem is I don't know how to make a deep link from this link "https://developer.wisdom.com/j?otp=2etrrf-u57rury5-5u5u57r&email=test@test.com&key=243464yrhffutjt758586869jg869t9"

i have tried

```
<data android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="developer.wisdom.com"
                        android:pathPrefix="/"                      
                        />
```

I want the URL above to open my app when clicked and also be able to access the otp and key

Answer (score 0):

When you pass query parameters in a deeplink URL, the Intent that starts the activity that listens the URL contains the query parameters in the Extras. You can access then inside the onCreate method using

```
getIntent().getExtras(). getString("email");
```

Edit: note that the intent is not fired when you type the url on the Chrome. The app should be opened only when you click a link or receive a redirect

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, this URL " https://developer.wisdom.com/j?otp=2etrrf-u57rury5-5u5u57r&email=test@test.com&key=243464yrhffutjt758586869jg869t9" doesn't open my app. but if I use " developer.wisdom.com " it will open my app

Comment: Thanks guys, i finally found the answer

Comment: I was missing "s" in my host which is Http instead of Https